# How to navigate in a circle

Tags: java, user-interface, blackberry

the title might be not very descriptive but i couldn't think of a better one.

The problem is as follows:
I have one screen (ScreenOne) with a link to another screen (ScreenTwo).
On the ScreenTwo is a link back to ScreenOne.

I implemented this via custom RichTextFields and a custom ChangeListener.

Now the problem is that i keep getting a StackOverflowError!
Is there any way to navigate back and forth in that way?

regards matt

```
public class MyApp extends UiApplication
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        MyApp theApp = new MyApp();       
        theApp.enterEventDispatcher();
    }

    public MyApp()
    {
        ScreenOne so = ScreenProvider.getInstance().getScreenOne();
        so.initialize();
        ScreenProvider.getInstance().getScreenTwo().initialize();
        pushScreen(so);
    }    
}

public class ScreenOne extends MainScreen {
    MyTextField link;

    public ScreenOne() {
        link = new MyTextField("FirstScreen");
        add(link);
    }

    public void initialize(){
        link.setChangeListener((FieldChangeListener) new MyFieldChangeListener(ScreenProvider.getInstance().getScreenTwo()));
    }
}

public class ScreenTwo extends MainScreen {
    MyTextField link;

    public ScreenTwo() {
        link = new MyTextField("SecondScreen");
        add(link);
    }

    public void initialize(){
        link.setChangeListener((FieldChangeListener) new MyFieldChangeListener(ScreenProvider.getInstance().getScreenOne()));
    }
}

public class MyFieldChangeListener implements FieldChangeListener {

    private Screen nextScreen;

    public MyFieldChangeListener(Screen nextScreen) {
        this.nextScreen = nextScreen;
    }

    public void fieldChanged(Field field, int context) {
        UiApplication.getUiApplication().pushScreen(nextScreen);
    }
}

public class MyTextField extends RichTextField {
    public MyTextField() {
        super();
    }

    public MyTextField(String text) {
        super(text);
    }

    protected boolean touchEvent(TouchEvent message) {
        if (TouchEvent.CLICK == message.getEvent()) {
            FieldChangeListener listener = getChangeListener();
            if (null != listener)
                listener.fieldChanged(this, 1);
        }
        return super.touchEvent(message);
    }
}

public class ScreenProvider {
    private static ScreenProvider instance = null;

    private ScreenProvider(){}

    public static ScreenProvider getInstance() {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new ScreenProvider();
        }
        return instance;
    }

    private ScreenOne screenOne = new ScreenOne();
    private ScreenTwo screenTwo = new ScreenTwo();

    public ScreenOne getScreenOne() {
        return screenOne;
    }

    public ScreenTwo getScreenTwo() {
        return screenTwo;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your ScreenProvider you don't need to make screen1/screen2 static -- they're members of the singleton instance.

Outside of that the other problem I see in this current version is that you're going to be pushing a screen onto the stack -- that's already on the stack.    Try popping the prior screen first.

Comment: I added a way of popping the previous Screen, but it still doesn't work

Answer (score 2):

The constructor of ScreenOne creates a ScreenTwo instance, and the constructor of ScreenTwo creates a ScreenOne instance. You have an infinite loop here.

Comment: I don't see why this one wouldn't work. Please post the stack trace of the exception and tell us which line of code corresponds to which line number in the stack trace.

Comment: I'm not able do debug, so I think it's not possible to get the StackTrace :(

Comment: You can get the stack trace by going to the event log from the home screen, ALT+L ALT+G ALT+L ALT+G

Answer (score 1):

Regarding **revision 5** of this question:

> new ScreenProvider() -> new ScreenOne() -> ScreenProvider.getInstance() -> new ScreenProvider() -> ...

still infinite.   Again, the problem is that you're trying to setup a cycle via object constructors.   You need to create the objects first, then assign the next and previous.

Regarding **revision 4** of this question:

> getScreenOne() -> new ScreenOne() -> getScreenTwo() -> new ScreenTwo() -> getScreenOne() -> newScreenOne() -> ...

you still have an infinite loop, because the constructors are trying to store an instance of each other.  You need to construct the objects first, then add the cyclic references.

Comment: could you explain that in more detail or post an example, I'm not quite sure what you mean...

Comment: I adapted the code above (still not working), is this what you meant?

Comment: **revision 6** another try. I now separated the construction and the cycle setup. It's now giving me a RuntimeException when clicking on the link on the ScreenTwo.

Comment: Does revision 6 compile without error?  The code calls the MyFieldChangeListener constructor with one argument, but there is only a two-argument constructor. This shouldn't work.  Eclipse will run code with compiler errors - it just inserts exceptions where the compilation errors are.  That may be what you are seeing now.

Comment: rev 7 looks good, based on my visual inspection.   Are you still seeing problems?

Answer (score 0):

That overflow error is likely the result of an infinite loop caused by constantly jumping from ScreenOne and ScreenTwo. Could you describe what you actually would want to accomplish and/or show a snippet of code?

Comment: I also thought about that, but also writing the Screens as Singletons didn't help. (going to post more code) The purpose of this constellation is that i want wo implement a sort of "tab view" where i  need to navigate between the particular "tabs"

Comment: Added an other version, trying to avoid creating a new Object when clicking the link.